# Storage Spaces blocking IO to other drives if busy?

Tags: storage, storage-spaces

I am currently experimenting a bit with Microsoft Storage Spaces on Win10 Pro.

I currently have a pool of 5 x 8 TB Seagate Ironwolf.
Within that pool I created a parity protected virtual Disk, 8TB in size, with Interleave 64K and NumberOfColumns 5 (experimenting with these values).

Currently is being formatted by VeraCrypt, so the whole drive is 100% busy for 8TBs of writes. Now I see that the performance is pretty bad, but I already wrote that Storage Spaces Parity is not really performant with only 5 disks, but I just want to test some stuff.

Now, while the virutal disk is busy being formatted, I am experiencing IO "stalls" on the rest of the system.

The rest of my system runs on either M.2 NVMe SSDs or SATA SSDs. When I open websites, my browser tells me "waiting for cache" which takes a few 10 seconds, if I open a folder on a SSD the folder can take a few seconds to open, and every file transaction seems to take a few seconds to initiate.
To me it seems that Storage Spaces is interrupting File IO to the rest of the system, it looks like some kind of global IO queue is fully used by Storage Spaces and new requests need to wait untill the current pending Storage Spaces requests are finished. The individual SSDs are 0% busy. Once the transaction starts, it goes full speed, for example copying a big file to or from the SSDs.

The IO Queue in Ressource monitor looks like this
[resmon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbxnP.png)

I am taking a big hit in system useability while Storage Spaces is busy.

Is this behaviour known? Is there some way to prevent Storage Spaces to block other system IO?